# fix vs. ArrowLoop

Tags: loops, haskell, arrows, fixpoint-combinators

Description of `loop` from `Control.Arrow`:

> The loop operator expresses computations in which an output value is fed back as input, although the computation occurs only once. It underlies the rec value recursion construct in arrow notation.

Its source code, and its instantiation for `(->)`:

```
class Arrow a => ArrowLoop a where
    loop :: a (b,d) (c,d) -> a b c

instance ArrowLoop (->) where
    loop f b = let (c,d) = f (b,d) in c
```

This immediately reminds me of `fix`, the fixpoint combinator:

```
fix :: (a -> a) -> a
fix f = let x = f x in x
```

So my question is:

1. Is it possible to implement that particular `loop` via `fix`?
2. How are their functionalities different?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Well, of course. Every recursive definition can be written with `fix`:

   ```
   loop f b = let (c, d) = f (b, d) in c
   loop f b = fst $ let (c, d) = f (b, d) in (c, d)
   loop f b = fst $ let x = f (b, d) in x
   loop f b = fst $ let x = f' x in x
     where f' (_, d) = f (b, d)
   loop f b = fst $ fix $ f . (b,) . snd
   ```

   And it works the other way around:

   ```
   fix f = loop (join (,) . f . snd) ()
   ```
2. The above should convince you that `loop` and `fix` are equivalently powerful when talking about `(->)`. Why, then, if arrows are meant to generalize functions, is `ArrowLoop` not defined like so?

   ```
   class Arrow a => ArrowLoop a where
     fix :: a b b -> b
   ```

   Arrows also generalize the notion of "process": when `Arrow a`, `a b c` is a way to calculate a `c` from a `b`. If `ArrowLoop` was defined to directly generalize `fix`, then it would be severely crippled. `fix` would have to "execute" the process without any context and directly produce a value of type `b`, which means the "process" `a b b` cannot e.g. perform `IO`. Or, consider the arrow

   ```
   newtype LT i o = LT { runLT :: [i] -> [o] }
   ```

   You’d like it if `fix` would produce a `[b]` from a `LT b b`, but it doesn’t.

   `loop` is a way around these restrictions. It takes a process as argument and produces a process as result. In a sense, all the context associated with the first process can be survived in the second, which would not be possible if `loop` were more like `fix`.

   Note that I can implement an analogue of `fix` for `ArrowLoop`s:

   ```
   -- resulting process ignores its input
   fix' :: ArrowLoop a -- taking an impl of loop as argument
        => a b b -> a u b
   fix' f = loop ((id &&& id) . f . arr snd)
   -- take off the outer application to () (application means (->), after all)
   -- and arrowify: join (,) = id &&& id; snd = arr snd; (Prelude..) = (Control.Category..)
   -- but the RHSs are more general
   ```

   But I don't believe

   ```
   loop' :: Arrow a => (forall x u. a x x -> a u x) -- taking an impl of fix' as argument
         -> a (b, d) (c, d) -> a b c
   ```

   is implementable, so we can’t base `ArrowLoop` on `fix'` either.

Comment: In the case of something like `Kleisli IO`, isn't `mfix` enough?

Comment: @dfeuer Yes, but there are arrows that are not based on monads (which is kind of the point of arrows) that can’t make do with `fix`. Further, as I was playing around writing this answer, I tried to implement `loop`y things in terms of `fix`y things and kept hitting vaguely `ArrowApply`-shaped roadblocks (and those are related to monads). So, I think that "a `fix`y thing is enough for arrow `a`" might even be equivalent to "`a` is a `Kleisli` arrow". We don’t *want* to be restricted to `Kleisli` arrows, so we need `loop`.

Comment: I just meant that your comment about purity being required was too strong.

Comment: @dfeuer I meant "pure" in the general sense of "without any context", not in the more specific sense of "not `IO`". I’ll see if I can reword it.

Comment: You say the process `a b b` can't perform `IO`, but that doesn't seem right.

Comment: @dfeuer I said the argument of the hypothetical `fix`, an `a b b`, would not be able to perform `IO`. This is true. In general, it isn’t. We’d like to keep it false even if `ArrowLoop a`, so `ArrowLoop` can’t be based on `fix`.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I mixed up `fix` with `fix'`.