# Cases in which we shall not use monadic bind to write mfix down using loop

Tags: haskell, monads, arrows, fixpoint-combinators

I have been trying to write `mfix` down using [`Control.Arrow.loop`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/src/Control.Arrow.html#loop). I came up with different definitions and would like to see which one is `mfix`'s actual workalike.

So, the solution I reckon to be the right one is the following:

```
mfix' :: MonadFix m => (a -> m a) -> m a
mfix' k = let f ~(_, d) = sequenceA (d, k d)
          in (flip runKleisli () . loop . Kleisli) f
```

As one can see, the `loop . Kleisli`'s argument works for `Applicative` instances. I find it to be a good sign as we mostly have our knot-tying ruined by `(>>=)`'s strictness in the right argument.

Here is another function. I can tell that it is not `mfix`'s total workalike, but the only case I found is *not very natural*. Take a look:

```
mfix'' k = let f ~(_, d) = fmap ((,) d) (return d >>= k)
           in (flip runKleisli () . loop . Kleisli) f
```

As far as I understand, not every strict on the right-hand bind forces its argument entirely. For example, in case of `IO`:

```
GHCi> mfix'' ((return :: a -> IO a) . (1:))
[1,1,1,1,1,Interrupted.
```

So, I decided to fix this. I just took `Maybe` and forced `x` in `Just x >>= k`:

```
data Maybe' a = Just' a | Nothing' deriving Show

instance Functor Maybe' where
    fmap = liftM

instance Applicative Maybe' where
    pure  = return
    (<*>) = ap

instance Monad Maybe' where
    return         = Just'
    Nothing' >>= k = Nothing'
    Just' x  >>= k = x `seq` k x

instance MonadFix Maybe' where
    mfix f = let a = f (unJust' a) in a
             where unJust' (Just' x) = x
                   unJust' Nothing'  = errorWithoutStackTrace "mfix Maybe': Nothing'."
```

Having this on our hands:

```
GHCi> mfix ((return :: a -> Maybe' a) . (1:))
[1,1,1,1,1,Interrupted.

GHCi> mfix' ((return :: a -> Maybe' a) . (1:))
[1,1,1,1,1,Interrupted.

GHCi> mfix'' ((return :: a -> Maybe' a) . (1:))
Interrupted.
```

So, here are my questions:

1. Is there any other example which could show that `mfix''` is not
   totally `mfix`?
2. Are monads with such a strict bind, like `Maybe'`,
   interesting in practice?
3. Are there any examples which show that `mfix'` is not totally `mfix` that I have not found?

---

**A small side note on `IO`:**

```
mfix3 k' = 
    let 
       k = return . k'
       f ~(_, d) = fmap ((,) d) (d >>= k)
    in (join . flip runKleisli () . loop . Kleisli) f
```

Do not worry about all the `return`s and `join`s - they are here just to have `mfix3`'s and `mfix`'s types match. The idea is that we pass `d` itself instead of `return d` to the `(>>=)` on the right-hand. It gives us the following:

```
GHCi> mfix3 ((return :: a -> IO a) . (1:))
Interrupted.
```

Yet, for example **(thanks to [Li-yao Xia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6863749/li-yao-xia) for their comment)**:

```
GHCi> mfix3 ((return :: a -> e -> a) . (1:)) ()
[1,1,1,1,1,Interrupted.
```

---

**Edit: thanks to [HTNW](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5684257/htnw)  for an important note on pattern-matching in the comments: it is better to use `\ ~(_, d) -> ...`, not `\ (_, d) -> ...`.**

Comment: [I did this too, a while back](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51759186/5684257). The last `fix'` is almost `mfix`. Comparing it to yours, I think you're missing some laziness (you use `\(_, d) -> ` while I use `\~(_, d) -> ` (hidden inside `snd`), which may or may not be important. Don't actually have the answers here, but thought it might be interesting. Also, `Maybe'` is not a monad: `return undefined >>= const x` should be `x` but is `undefined`. Of course, that doesn't stop us from doing it (e.g. I think MTL's `Writer` is similarly not a monad)...

Comment: @HTNW thank you - I edited the post.

Comment: Note that `(print >> return) = return`. This is `(>>)` in the reader monad, which ignores its first argument, so this has nothing to do with IO. These examples are not demonstrating what you think they're demonstrating.

Comment: @Li-yaoXia yes, I guess I messed up with the `IO` - thank you. Yet please note that `mfix3 (return . (1:))` is not a bottom for every monad. For example, `mfix3 ((return :: a -> e -> a) . (1:)) ()` produces output. I will edit the post so it is not confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a partial answer, which I hope is better than no answer.

> Is there any other example which could show that mfix'' is not totally mfix?

We can distinguish `mfix''` from `mfix` also by making `return` strict instead of `(>>=)`.

> Are monads with such a strict bind, like Maybe', interesting in practice?

Probably not. (Questions about the existence of "practical" examples are not easy to answer negatively.)

Containers that are strict in their elements might be an example of this. (In case you're wondering about the official containers package, it does not actually define `Monad` instances for `Map` and `IntMap`, and the `Monad` instance of `Seq` is lazy in the elements of the sequence).

Note also that it is unclear whether the monad laws take strictness into account. If you do, then such things are not lawfully monads because they break the left identity law: `(return x >>= k) = k x` for `x = undefined`.

> Are there any examples which show that `mfix'` is not totally `mfix` that I have not found?

If you take the definition of `loop` in the standard library, in terms of `mfix`, then I think that `mfix' = mfix`, though I couldn't complete a proof (I could either be missing a good trick, or there's a missing MonadFix law).

The main point of contention, as was hinted at in the comments, is strictness. Both your definition of `mfix'` and the standard library's definition of `loop` are careful to expand the argument function to be lazier (using lazy patterns (`~(_, d)`) and `snd` respectively; the two techniques are equivalent). `mfix` and `mfix'` are still equal if exactly one of those precautions is dropped. There is a mismatch (`mfix /= mfix'`) if both are dropped.

Comment: You mentioned containers which are strict in their elements. If I write `Maybe' a = Just' !a | Nothing'`, do you think it would differ much from what we have in the post? `>>=` and, therefore, `liftM` and `ap` have already been strict. Basically, we turn `return` (and `pure`) strict. Truth be told, I could not think of an example which would work with strict `>>=` and lazy `return`, but not with both strict `>>=` and `return`. Do you happen to have any ideas?

Comment: Truth be told, the intuition tells me “no” as I cannot see how we would manage with `return x` without `>>=` (see `mfix''`). `<*>`, `<$>` and `join` would not be of much help either as in my example they are written down with `Control.Monad` functions which use binding. Yet, I reckon this to be a quite weak reasoning. Probably, incorrect. Anyway, am I right?

Comment: My intuition is also that it matters very little which one of `(>>=)` or `return` is strict.